# How to show *just* the menu 'hamburger' when page at mobile phone width?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, navbar, responsive

I am a CSS beginner, so far using css only to change colours and size, while copying and pasting for things like JavaScript. Thus I am trying to adjust an responsive navigation bar from w3schools.com that generally looks what I require.

My problem is when the screen width is reduced to mobile width, the result, as well as the three lines (hamburger), there is also the word 'Home' rather than just the three lines. The code I've used comes from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav, while my test page is at 
https://www.abelard.org/mobile/test1.php.

It looked to me as if the code section

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

It appeared to me to be the relevant area controlling the nav bar display, my alteration removing the line `.topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}` makes no difference. I cannot see where else might help.

```
html...
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img src="/library/menu-burger-grn.png">
    </a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>test page for nav bar</h2>
    <p>First step</p>
    </div>

   <script>
   function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
     if (x.className === "topnav") {
       x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
     }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>

style.css...

    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Add your `HTML` for your navbar to your post.

Comment: Sorry thatnot done before

Comment: I added a fiddle at (https://jsfiddle.net/r3gxh0bL/), you can add to this. Your hamburger icon is not there as you have it loading from a local resource.

Comment: Dear Ryan Wilson Given your comment about the local image, I have replaced it for the moment with a glyph from an online css file. The link to that file has been added to the head area of the html file. However, when I reduce the width of the now updated fiddle result, the menu area turns into a stack on the left and there is no three menu lines. (This was also happening before my update, which I then updated to check whether the image was causing interference.) Can you advise?

Comment: Dear Ryan Wilson
I have done more tests using your very helpful fiddle. I found that changing the first media query  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
so the second line reads   .topnav a {display: none;} rather than   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
provides the result I want. 
I have re-saved the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7muycnep/1/ so it now gives the result I want when reducing the screen width.
Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Good job. You can always post your change as an answer so that someone who encounters your post can view your answer on this page. Also, you can then choose to accept it as the accepted answer.